# Secure crossdomain for rtmp/flash streaming/wowza

Tags: flash, crossdomain, crossdomain.xml

I've been a bit lost. I have the following situation:

Flash Player file is on `https://sub.example.com/player.swf`

`crossdomain.xml` is on `https://sub2.example.com/crossdomain.xml`

Streaming is done using [Wowza](https://www.wowza.com/).

The `crossdomain.xml` right now is everything but tight:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I've tried to figure this out myself and have read the following posts about this:

- http://sethsec.blogspot.ch/2014/03/exploiting-misconfigured-crossdomainxml.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215127/how-do-i-specify-a-crossdomain-policy-file-to-allow-flash-to-grab-a-bitmap-from
  (especially answer two)
- https://forums.adobe.com/thread/422391
- https://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?45081-The-function-of-crossdomain-xml
- https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AppSec/xdomain.html

Still my question remains and is:
How should the crossdomain.xml look like in this case to protect properly and why? There are no reasons other players should access the stream besides `player.swf` on the different subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

A properly locked down policy would look like this in your situation:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="sub.example.com" secure="true"/>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Allowing `*` wildcard for all domains means that user sessions on `sub2.example.com` could be compromised by a malicious Flash app on another domain that the users visits.